# Regex: finding several linebreaks

Tags: regex, line, line-breaks

hi i'm having this html markup

```
<body>
<table border="0" width="50%" align="center">
<tr>
<td>




<center>
```

and i'm trying to find a "wildcard" for the linebreaks to reach the `<center>` tag - how would this work?

thx

Comment: `<center>` cannot hold it is too late http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal RegEx to find a repeating linebreak is "[\r\n]+" which means at least 1 linebreak. This will match any number of linebreaks following directly after each other.

Comment: Will not match "empty lines" that have a tab or other spaces on them, and will also match ALL line breaks, not just multiple consecutive lines of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
/(\s*\n){2,}/
```

Since some platforms use `\r\n` as their line-break, and some use only `\n` this will search for 
successive strings of whitespace (which \r should also be considered) followed by `\n`, and ensure to match 2 of them.

Firebug console test:

```
>>> /(\s*\n){2,}/.exec("<tr>\r\n<td> \r\n \t \r\n \n\n<center>");
[" \r\n \r\n \n\n", "\n"]
```